# Function parameter with colon

Tags: python, function

I just came across this function:

```
def splitComma(line: str):
    splits = Utils.COMMA_DELIMITER.split(line)
    return "{}, {}".format(splits[1], splits[2])
```

I am aware that you can separate parameters by , or can set a value within a parameter like `a=39` but I have not seen a colon like `line:str`. I have checked the function definition online but could not find anything like this. What does this colon mean?

Comment: Note: the duplicate discusses variable annotations, which were new to Python 3.6. This is about an ordinary function annotation, which was introduced in Python 3.0.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

It's a function annotation; function arguments and the return value can be tagged with arbitrary Python expressions. Python itself ignores the annotation (other than saving it), but third-party tools can make use of them.

In this case, it is intended as type hint: programs like [mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy) can analyze your code statically (that is, without running it, but only looking at the source code itself) to ensure that only `str` values are passed as arguments to `splitComma`.

A fuller annotation to also specify the return type of the function:

```
def splitComma(line: str) -> str:
    ...
```

(Note that originally, function annotations weren't assumed to have any specific semantics. This is still true, but the overwhelming *assumption* these days is that the annotations provide type hints.)

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. This is interesting especially for someone comming from a language where setting the type for in and output is coercively.

Comment: Omg, I had this on a coding interview. I was thinking, "what the fk is that???"  xD
Needless to say, I didn't get the job.

Comment: "A fuller annotation to also specify the return type of the function:" you meant function annotation?

Comment: @Geeocode No, fuller; the OP's only provided an annotation on the argument, rather than the argument and the return type.

Comment: Thank you chepner, for first reading I thought that "fuller" is some special notion, what I don't know, but now I realized that this is the literal meaning of fuller.

Comment: Why does Python ignore this? It would be as simple as comparing the `type` of the input. Is there some reason in the documentation or something? Just curious:)

Comment: Python is committed to remaining a dynamically typed language. It ignores the static type hints by choice, not because it would be difficult to enforce the type hints at run time. (This is also a simple case; being a dynamically typed language also means that there are situations where you cannot supply a static type hint that would capture the possible uses of a function.)

Comment: Is this means that, its like a comment, but written inside the code? As you said it will be ignored by Python. Can we say like that?

Comment: It's a little stronger than a comment. The parser removes comments so that they aren't part of the abstract syntax tree (AST) that is used to generate the executable code (byte code, in the case of CPython). Annotations, on the other hand, are retained and accessible at runtime if the code itself wants to see them.

Answer (score 16):

This is a [type annotation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) used by static analysis tools to check, well, types. It helps ensure program correctness before you run the code.