# What does x: int = 1.0 do?

Tags: python-3.x, syntax, initialization

I stumbled over the following code:

```
x: int = 1.0
```

and I wonder: what does it do (and why does it work at all - I expect this to be a SyntaxError)?

The only thing I found out is that the tpye of `x` is still `float`, so it is not equivalent to `x = int(1.0)`.

Comment: That's type annotation. Official doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are variable annotations in Python 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971929/what-are-variable-annotations-in-python-3-6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be found here: [Function parameter with colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54962869/function-parameter-with-colon) and here: [What are variable annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971929/what-are-variable-annotations)

In short ": int" is just an annotation designed as a form of comment that many programs use to analyze your code. It is presumed to have a format and indicate the type of the variable but is ignored by the interpreter.