# Python: pass dictionary variable as function argument

Tags: python, dictionary, variables

I am reusing a piece of code from another developer (it is a socket listener) which has the following function:

```
def start_my_client(self, *, config: dict):
```

I am new to Python, so I am assuming it requires a dictionary variable to be passed as an argument, so I created this variable:

```
config_dic = {'name': 'my_socket', 'hostname': 'test', 'description': 'TEST'}
```

However, I tried many different ways to pass the variable when calling the function, but none of them worked for me, for example:

```
def handle_messages(conn, addr):
    conn.start_my_client(config=config_dic)
```

I receive nothing from the function.
I tried this too:

```
def handle_messages(conn, addr):
    conn.start_my_client(**config_dic)
```

It throws this error:

```
TypeError: start_my_client() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

Any hint on how to pass the variable?

Comment: "I receive nothing from the function" - this is a different problem than the passing of argument, which is what is expected here.

Answer (score 0):

The first call looks reasonable

```
def handle_messages(conn, addr):
    conn.start_my_client(config=config_dic)
```

What is expected output for this?

If you pass config_dic like that

```
def handle_messages(conn, addr):
    conn.start_my_client(**config_dic)
```

you perform unpacking arguments here. This means that the method start_my_client get arguments the same way as if you would call method like that

```
conn.start_my_client(name='my_socket', hostname='test', description='TEST')
```

This is the reason you got error

```
TypeError: start_my_client() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

start_my_client doesnt expect argument called name.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in:

[What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

the function you are using can receive several different arguments:

```py
def start_my_client(self, *, config: dict):
```

So, it could take a number of arguments when called, something like this:

```py
conn.start_my_client(a, b, c)
```

As for the `:`, this

[Function parameter with colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54962869/function-parameter-with-colon)

Just indicate that each of the parameters passed should be `dicts`.

So, you could just call the function as:

```py
def handle_messages(conn, addr):
    conn.start_my_client(config_dic)
```